# Jetpack Compose: Loading Overlay controlled by separate function not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to show a loading overlay whit Jetpack Compose when the data is loading in background.

My problem is that I am not able to transfer a boolean variable declared with by remeber into a second function.

```
fun Show() {

    val showLoadingOverlay by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    loadDataInBackground(showLoadingOverlay)

    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        if (showLoadingOverlay) {
            Box(

                Modifier
                    .background(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.9f))
                    .matchParentSize()
            )

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                androidx.compose.material.CircularProgressIndicator()
                Text(text = "Loading, please wait ...")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
fun loadDataInBackground(showLoadingOverlay: Boolean) {

    thread {
        showLoadingOverlay = true

        // Do some loading stuff

        showLoadingOverlay = false
    }
}
```

**I already tried the following things:**

Change loadDataInBackground() param declaration to:

- showLoadingOverlay: SnapshotMutableState
- showLoadingOverlay: MutableState

This resulted to type missmatch error like:
**Required: MutableState Found: Boolean**

So if I change the type from Boolean to MutableState:

```
// From this
val showLoadingOverlay by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

// Into this
val showLoadingOverlay = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

I have problems showing the overlay:

```
// ...
if (showLoadingOverlay.value) {
// ...
```

This will cause a runtime error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reading a state that was created after the snapshot was taken or in a snapshot that has not yet been applied

**I also tried to insert another function as param:**

```
var isLoading by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

fun show() {
  var isLoading by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
  fun onLoadingChange(newLoading: Boolean)  {
            isLoading = newLoading
  }
  loadDataInBackground(onLoadingChange)
  // ..
}

fun loadDataInBackground(onLoadingChange: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    thread {
        onLoadingChange(true)

        // Do some loading stuff

        onLoadingChange(false)
    }
}
```

Also not working because I get the error:
**Type mismatch. Required: (Boolean) → Unit Found: Unit**
I have no idea how to solve it.